# JavaScript copy HTML to clipboard interprets < > as &lt; and &gt;

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can get JavaScript to copy the contents of a DIV into the clipboard, but the HTML tags < & > come out as < and > rather than the less than or greater than symbol. Any ideas how to fix? Link to fiddle which doesn't appear to work, but works locally. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e6xtn7wo/1/)

JS

```
function copyToClipboard(elementId) {

  // Create a "hidden" input
  var aux = document.createElement("input");

  // Assign it the value of the specified element
  aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);

  // Append it to the body
  document.body.appendChild(aux);

  // Highlight its content
  aux.select();

  // Copy the highlighted text
  document.execCommand("copy");

  // Remove it from the body
  document.body.removeChild(aux);

}
```

HTML

```
        <div style="display:none" >
    <p id="p1">Content 3 blocks</p></div>

<button onclick="copyToClipboard('p1')">Copy 1 section</button><br/>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('p2')">Copy 2 section</button><br/>



  <textarea name="textarea" id="p2" cols="45" rows="5"><div class="content-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h4 class="pumpkin-txt">Content Section - 4</h4>
                </div>
                <p>Some text here</p>
                <br>
                <h5>More text here</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></textarea>
```

Comment: Well don't use `.innerHTML` when you don't want HTML?

Comment: I thought that may have something to do with it, but if I remove it it breaks. What do I use instead of .innerHTML?

Comment: For normal elements, try `.textContent`, on a textarea you are looking for `.value`.

Comment: .textContent does work, thanks if you want to create an answer I'll vote you up!

Comment: @user3362232 Already created working version with innerHTML in answer below

Comment: Btw, you should not place html tags inside a textarea. They are rightfully degraded to HTML entities.

Comment: @Bergi if I change textarea to div or span it no longer works.

Comment: @user3362232: I didn't say you should do that. I said you should write proper HTML, like `<textarea>&lt;div%gt;…&lt;/div&gt;</textarea>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `innerHTML` is returning valid HTML content. "<" is not valid inner content in a node's value, as it is HTML code. You'll need to replace these yourself like this:

```
//Just an example, you need to replace all possible offending characters
aux.setAttribute(
    "value", 
    document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML.replace( /&lt;/g, "<" )
        .replace( /&gt;/g, ">" )
        .replace( /&quot;/g, "\"" )
);
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6xtn7wo/2/)